# Custom instance of Zend View and access to View Helpers

Tags: zend-framework2

I use Zend View to render HTML code to generate PDF file. My code looks like:

```
    $viewModel = new ViewModel(array(
        'order' => $order
    ));

    $viewModel->setTemplate('invoice');

    $resolver = new TemplatePathStack();
    $resolver->addPath(realpath(__DIR__ . '/../view/app'));

    $renderer = new PhpRenderer();
    $renderer->setResolver($resolver);

    $html = $renderer->render($viewModel);
```

And here I've got html code that I can pass to mPDF class to generate PDF document.

Anyway, I want to use View Helper in "invoice" template to do some stuff. If I define my custom helper in module.php file, it isn't accessible. So I need to define it in some another way, but I can't find how... Could you guys helper me?

Big thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach view helpers with name and reference to class name.

see https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.advanced-usage.html

Here is an example for you, expecting you are using a invokable plugin class.

```
...
$renderer = new PhpRenderer();
$renderer->setResolver($resolver);
$renderer->getHelperPluginManager()->setInvokableClass('viewhelpername', 'Path/To/Class');
```